# ReSharper support for custom razor directive

Tags: razor, resharper

I am extending MVC3 by overriding WebRazorHostFactory, MvcWebPageRazorHost and related classes to create a custom directive (like @model) that will change the base class of the view to a custom class deriving from WebPageBase, and will also add a second generic parameter to it.  Everything works and the class is generated correctly; however, ReSharper does not recognize the new directive.  Is there any way to extend ReSharper to recognize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can write such a plugin for ReSharper. But it's complicated and result is not guaranteed. Prepare yourself for many hours of looking at ReSharper's code with DotPeek. You can start by looking at RazorModelDirective, RazorCSharpMvcLanguage and RazorCSharpMvcLanguageService. You'd need to make classes similar to these.

Comment: After digging into the decompiled code for a while, it would appear that I would also need to write my own Razor .lex file from scratch.  Also, it is very difficult to understand the decompiled code since it seems to use constants pretty heavily, and these are getting lost at compile time.  Would it be possible to get a copy of the MVC/Razor specific source code (including .lex file) from which I could base my plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure about complete source code, but we can certainly give you some code samples where needed. Write me, my mail at jetbrains.com is Dmitry.Osinovsky (one letter different from my SO account name).

Answer (score 1):

James, in theory, it's possible by using ReSharper SDK.
But it will be pretty hardcore plugin, related to many subsystem.
If you will take actions in this direction, we can help you, answering specific questions.